# Изменить элементы массива в файле txt по столбцам

Tags: python

В txt файле есть:

```
   1: 0101100
  22: 0010010
 333: 1001000
4444: 0101100
5555: 0010010
```

задача заменить встречающиеся одиночные 1 на 0  по столбцам. Если столбец перевести в строку, произвести замены не получается внедрить обновлённый столбец. Попытка  использовать numpy np.genfromtxt транспонировать матрицу np.transpose, чтобы сделать .replace тоже не удалась. Похоже мешают пробелы перед номером строки, так перед 1 3 пробела, а в номере 4444 пробелов нет. Помогите

Comment: Приведите код этой попытки

Comment: считайте свой текстовый файл файлом csv, запихивайте его весь в pandas, модифицируйте, и записывайте целиком в новый файл.

Comment: @strawdog а какие будут колонки и разделители в этом csv?

Comment: @dIm0n `df = pd.read_csv("001.txt", sep=":", header=None)` ?

Comment: при чтении файла csv удаляются  нули с которых начинаются строки0  0:  1001001
1  1:   101100
2  2:    10010
3  3:  1001000
4  4:   101100
5  5:    10010

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("001.txt", sep=":", header=None, dtype="str") - укажите dtype. тогда все данные будут у вас строкового типа

Answer (score 2):

Работайте с pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("001.txt", sep=":", header=None, dtype="str")

# <Тут ваши манипуляции с датафреймом>

df.to_csv("002.csv", index=None, header=None, sep=":")
```

Comment: Кст, а нельзя ли использовать разделитель `": "`, чтобы в результате получить файл такого же формата?

Comment: @gil9red - при чтении можно указывать сепаратор длиной более 1 символа, но тогда он будет рассматриваться движком как regex

Comment: Спасибо. Оперативно, понятно, достаточно.